# How to call an unknown member function through an instance of a related class?

Tags: object-oriented, class, functions, pointers

I have two classes. The first, called `Game_Events`, controls the objects and manages the general tasks. The second, called `Button`, is for one of those object instances.

The example below is wrong but shows how I want to do it:

```
class Button
{
   public:
       Button(void (*f)()) : f_m(f)
       ~Button(){}

   private:
       void (*f_m);
};

class Game_Events()
{
    public:
        Game_Events()
        {
            button = new Button(&Close);
        }
        ~Game_Events(){}
        Close(){} //I need to pass this function for call it on the other side
}
```

So I want to create a `Button` instance inside of the `Game_Events` class and give it authority to call the `Close()` function of the same class as the instance owning the button. In the tile I say "unknown function", because the function to call is to be determined when the button is constructed.

Is that possible?

Comment: Usually this is done by subscribing to a UI "event," in this case `button.Click()`.

Comment: Yes it is possible. How it is done depends on the language, and possibly the API you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is definitively possible.

But there are two challenges to address in your design:

- `Close()` is a member function.  So if the button has to call this member function, it has to know on which object to call it.
- If later button has to action the call, you need to have it visible somehow in you rarchitecture (either it's a GUI element that performs the action when it's cliked, or it should be accessible pragrammatically inside your code.

I'll answer with C++.  For the second topic, for the sake of the demo, I'll assume that button would be a public member of Game_Events.

### Alternative 1: basic approach elaborating on your function pointer

If you don't need to call a member function, i.e. if `Close()` could be `static`, your code could work almost as it is, with some minor syntactic corrections:

```
class Button
{
   private:
       void (*f_m)();
   public:
       Button(void (*f)()) : f_m(f) {}
       ~Button(){}
       void operator() () { f_m(); }   // make button a callable (i.e. button() ) 
};
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/VT4Kci)

However the use is limited, because CLose would have to be static, so it could'nt use any object dependent vvalue of the game event.  What a pitty

### Alternative 2: approach abstracting the function to be called

So let's make it a little bit more general.  Instead of using a function pointer,  or a member function pointer (which would oblige us to determine the class of the function), we could use the functional library of C++, that allows to define ab abstract function:

```
#include <functional>
...
class Button
{
   private:
       function<void()> f_m;
   public:
       Button(function<void()> f) : f_m(f) {}
       ~Button(){}
       void operator() () { f_m(); }
};
```

Then you could create a button, with total flexibility for the function that you will provide.  Here I'll use a lambda function:

```
class Game_Events
{
    public:
        Button* button; 
        Game_Events()
        {
            button = new Button([this]()->void{this->Close(); });
        }
        ~Game_Events(){}
        void Close(){ cout<<"Boum"<<endl;} //I need to pass this function for call it on the other side
};
```

The requirement is that the object still exist when the button gets actioned.

[online demo](http://ideone.com/9zLYHf)

### Alternative 3: command design pattern

That's my favourite approach:  implement the [command pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/command-pattern.html).

The general principle is slightly changed compared to your original approach, but it's easier to handle and very powerful:

- You would have an abstract `Command` class with only one virtual member function:  `Execute()`.
- Your button constructor would be constructed with a pointer to an abstract `Command` object (instead of a function pointer).
- When your button is actioned, it just calls `Execute()` for the `Command` object.
- You would have a `CloseGameEvent` class inheriting from `Command`.  Its constructor would keep track of the `Game_Event` and its overriden `Execute()` would call the `Close()` function for it.
- When you construct your button object, you'd then pass it the relevant `CloseGameEvent`.